# Prove a system of equations: $x = {t^2 + 1\over 2t}$, $y = {t^2 - 1\over 2t}$ defines two continuous on $\Bbb R$ functions $x(y)$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, parametric

> Given a system of equations: 
>   $$x = {t^2 + 1\over 2t}\\
> y = {t^2 - 1\over 2t}$$ 
>   Prove that it defines two continuous functions $x(y)$ on $\Bbb R$ and four continuous functions $y(x)$ on $\{x: |x|\ge 1\}$

I can not really understand what the author of the problem mean by two functions on $R$ and four functions on $|x| \ge 1$. Obviously for $t = 0$ neither $x(t)$ nor $y(t)$ is defined. So we only consider $t\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$. For this domain the ranges are:
$$
x(t) \in(-\infty, -1)\cup(1, +\infty)\\
y(t) \in \Bbb R
$$

Now let's express $t$ in terms of $x$ and $y$:
$$
x = {t^2 + 1\over 2} \iff t^2 - 2xt + 1 = 0 \\
t_{1,2} = x\pm\sqrt{x^2 -1}
$$
Similarly:
$$
y = {t^2 - 1\over 2} \iff t^2 - 2yt - 1 = 0 \\
t_{3,4} = y\pm\sqrt{y^2 + 1}
$$

Since those are the only solutions for $t$ we need to consider 4 cases:
$$
t_1 = t_3 \\
t_1 = t_4 \\
t_2 = t_3 \\
t_2 = t_4
$$
Start with $t_1 = t_3$, then it would mean:
$$
x + \sqrt{x^2 - 1} = y + \sqrt {y^2 - 1} \\
x - y = \sqrt{y^2 + 1} - \sqrt{x^2 - 1} \\
(x - y)^2 = \left(\sqrt{y^2 + 1} - \sqrt{x^2 - 1}\right)^2 \\
xy = \sqrt{(y^2 + 1)(x^2 - 1)} \\
(xy)^2 = (y^2 + 1)(x^2 - 1) \\
x^2 - y^2 = 1
$$

Other cases yield the same result. So basically we've arrived at the equation:
$$
x^2 - y^2 = 1 \tag 1
$$

Now no matter what function we define, either $y(x)$ or $x(y)$ each defines a single function, which [are essentially the same](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fydma8qngq):
$$
|x| = \sqrt{y^2 + 1}\\
|y| = \sqrt{x^2 - 1}
$$

So how could a parametric function define several functions? Is that because we need to split the domain somehow and consider various cases for $x<0, y<0$; $x<0, y>0$ and etc.?